# How to Rescue OS X without Visible Startup Disc?

Tags: macos, startup, partition, recovery, efi

I need to delete [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uinst_osx) but I cannot do it because I bypass it, since I cannot see visible startup disc. 
I stopped partition process where I tried to erase Linux partition because of infinite time in the process. 
There are no directories `/etc/refind.d/` and `/boot/efi/EFI/refind` in my system. I am now in Recovery Mode where you cannot see the startup disk in `Startup Disk`.

The problem with `refind` is that it shows at startup just the Linux partition which is broken. If I click it, the thing goes to `grub>` where I already did this based on the [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493826/grub-rescue-problem-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition)

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1) # try to recognize which partition is this
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2) # let's assume this is the linux partition
grub rescue > set root=(hd0,msdos2)
grub rescue > set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub # or wherever grub is installed
grub rescue > insmod normal # if this produced an error, reset root and prefix to something else ..
grub rescue > normal
```

where I selected the HSF+ disk for the boot. The problem is that this will not bypass `refind`.

---

How can rescue OS X without visible Startup disk and with refind?

Comment: yeah I got that. But better remove your (accepted) answer because it's no viable solution to the problem...

Comment: @klanomath I just want to get an answer to this thread so I know that I do not have the problem now. I will otherwise regularly read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to delete OS X because I did not get help enough fast. I needed my computer. Klanomath's proposal seems to be forward

1. Boot to Recovery Mode please
2. Do `diskutil list`
3. Do `gpt -r show disk0` in Terminal.app
4. Add output/screenshot here